# Dúvida sobre eventos em uma função Javascript

Tags: javascript

Vou tentar resumir

Estava com um problema com um onclick em um botão, e consegue resolver usando e.preventDefault();

Porém surgiu a dúvida, para funcionar tive que adicionar "e" a minha função e ficou `function myFunction(e)`
E no meu código html tive que colocar o onclick dessa forma

```
onclick="addList(event)"
```

Tentei buscar sobre event e talvez não tenha procurado da forma correta mas não encontrei, eu acreditava que os valores em função eram opcionais, mas nesse caso tive uma supresa, pois só funciona exatamente dessa forma, usando *(event)* no onclick e *(e)* na função.

Alguem pode me dar uma luz nessa parte? Fiquei confuso

Comment: Poderia postar o código? Assim fica mais fácil entender sua dúvida. Adiantando o comportamento padrão de um form é submit, `e.preventDefault();` indica que você deseja prevenir o comportamento padrão.

Comment: Marconi na verdade a minha dúvida é: por que no onclick devo colocar (event) e no função devo colocar (e) para funcionar. Pra mim ficou confuso porque em um devo escrever "event" completo e no outro somente "e". Mas se ficou confuso eu postarei o código aqui, é que não tenho muito jeito de como postar no forum mas dou um jeito haha

Comment: Henrique faça um tour, vai entender direitinho como funciona por aqui!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua aplicação JavaScript é reativa aos eventos do HTML. Ou seja, quando o usuário clicar em um botão, você consegue adicionar um *handler* para que defina algum comportamento quando esse botão for clicado, por exemplo, fazer uma requisição HTTP.

Para adicionar um *handler* de evento é simples, usa-se o `addEventListener`:

```js
document.querySelector('#meu-botao').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('O botão foi clicado');
});
```

```html
<button id="meu-botao">Clique-me</button>
```

Os eventos podem ter comportamentos prévios aos que você define. Por exemplo:

- Quando você clica em um `<a href="...">`, o navegador te redireciona para uma página
- Quando você clica no botão de *submit* de um elemento `<form>`, uma requisição HTTP será feita
- Quando você aperta a seta do teclado, o navegador fará um *scroll*

Todos esses comportamentos são chamados de comportamentos-padrão e são definidos pelo navegador.

Mas e se você quiser criar um jogo para rodar no navegador e precisar utilizar as setas para terem um outro comportamento? Aí é que entra o [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

> Cancela o evento se for cancelável, sem parar a propagação do mesmo.

Na citação, é se for cancelável pois alguns navegadores não permitem que você sobrescreva um comportamento-padrão. Por exemplo: nenhum navegador vai te deixar sobrescrever o <kbd>ALT+F4</kbd>.

Veja um exemplo de um *checkbox* com seu comportamento sobrescrito:

```js
let prevent = document.querySelector("#prevent");
let noPrevent = document.querySelector("#no-prevent");

prevent.addEventListener("click", event => {
  console.log('clicou!');
  event.preventDefault();
});

noPrevent.addEventListener("click", event => {
  console.log('clicou!');
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="prevent">com preventDefault
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="no-prevent">sem preventDefault
```

O `e` que você comentou, é o `event` nas funções que citei. Todo evento propagado tem uma instância de [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) atrelado. Dele é possível ter informações importantes do evento, e funções como o `preventDefault`.

Comment: Obrigado, ficou bem claro pra mim !